# Vertical vs. Horizontal Masonry CSS-only

Tags: css, masonry

I implemented "masonry" on my site using [css-only](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/), but at the moment the items display vertically, while I'd like it to display horizontally.

Current:

```
1 | 4 | 7
2 | 5 | 8 
3 | 6 | 9
```

Desired:

```
1 | 2 | 3
4 | 5 | 6 
7 | 8 | 9
```

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: css columns use columns, so if you use that CSS then you will get column order. If you want a CSS only solution for modern browsers, then google flexbox.